# Usage of "here" and "there"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Suppose I'm pointing at a location on a map where I never go to, which of the following sentences are correct:

- I never go there
- I never go here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either. There's possibly a difference in the implied timing of the pointing action. I would use there and here like this:

> [points] I never go there.

and

> I never go [points] here.

Comment: Never thought about it, that's actually pretty neat